# Debug ASP .Net WebAPI locally with an Android App

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP .Net Web API as a Server and using an emulator to test the changes of my Android app. I am stuck with a problem for quite some time. I wanted to debug my WebAPI locally with the emulator. However, my java code fails to hit my API with the below error

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.2 (port 63016): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

As mentioned in the error, i am trying the below URL

> public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "https://10.0.0.2:63016/api/MyApp/"

What am i missing?

Comment: Looks like the access is blocked. Did you try to configure the firewall?

Comment: @DinoTw No, i did no changes to my firewall settings. What do i need to do?

Comment: It depends on what OS your server is running on. For Ubuntu, you can refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html. Just google the firewall configuration for your OS.

Comment: @DinoTw Well, I am using a Windows 10 operated system. I checked the firewall settings for the Android Studio app and it shows that Android Studio is let through the firewall.

Comment: For firewall, it does not matter what the client is. Normally what I do is to use a browser to see if I can get a response from the server.

Comment: @DinoTw The WebAPIs are responding well from my advanced rest client(ARC)

Comment: I see you use https, is your web server really running on https or just http?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157397/discussion-between-anee-and-dino-tw).